# I want to manufacture a product that is patented but no longer produced

Tags: lapsed

The original manufacturer still holds the patent (US5787839 Lapsed ) but no longer produces the item. What are my options to license or buy the patent?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the patent number. With that, we can give you a much better answer.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if you provided the patent number. Assuming the patent is lapsed due to non-payment of maintenance fees, the patent isn't enforceable. However it may be possible to revive a lapsed patent. [This is the USPTO page](https://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s2590.html) covering this process. Here is another [webpage](http://patentassociate.com/patentblog/2016/09/21/reviving-abandoned-patents/) with more information. If the patent has reached its regular expiration date of 20 years after the filing (or priority) date including any patent term extensions, then it can not be revived.

Edit: [US5787839](https://patents.google.com/patent/US5787839A/en?oq=US5787839) was granted in 1998-08-04 and has a priority date of 1994-07-22. Patents from that era expire either 20 years from the priority date or 17 years from the grant date whichever is later. Either way, that patent is now expired. You should have no reason to need a license. That said, you may want to look at the [patents that cite US5787830](https://patents.google.com/patent/US5787839A/en?oq=US5787839#citedBy) as this might lead you to a newer relevant patent.